# Error SQL: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Administrator'. at

Tags: sql, login, sharepoint

Tengo el siguiente error en mi página de SharePoint y trato de conectarme a una base de datos pero me da error. No sé a que se debe ya que tengo privilegios de administrador

```
SqlConnection conection = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
Source=SHAREPOINT\SHAREPOINTDB;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXDATA;Integrated 
Security=False;User ID=Administrator;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

**Aquí la excepción completa:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Administrator'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at ExpotranDocumentsWebPart.ExpotranDocumentsVisualWebPart.ExpotranDocumentsVisualWebPart.SQLSearchFiles(DateTime lastSearchDate) ClientConnectionId:162a51a1-a376-416d-b2a8-81e3ea5b298c Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

Answer (score 2):

Debe adicionarse un parámetro más al connectionstring para que se tenga en cuenta la información de autentificación que se incluye en la asignación.

`Persist Security Info=true`

La cadena de conexión quedaría así:

```
SqlConnection conection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHAREPOINT\SHAREPOINTDB;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXDATA;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Administrator;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Una [referencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) en msdn.microsoft.com dice:

> **Traducción:** El parámetro ConnectionString (En SqlConnection) es similar a la cadena de conexión en OLE DB, pero no idéntica. A diferencia de OLE DB o ADO, la cadena de conexión que es retornada es la misma que la asignada por el usuario **menos** la información de seguridad si el parámetro `Persis Security Info` está puesto en falso. El proveedor para SQL Server del Framework de .NET no persiste o retorna la contraseña en una cadena de conexión a menos que usted ponga en `true` el valor de `Persis Security Info`.
>
> **Original:** The ConnectionString is similar to an OLE DB connection string, but is not identical. Unlike OLE DB or ADO, the connection string that is returned is the same as the user-set ConnectionString, minus security information if the Persist Security Info value is set to false (default). The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not persist or return the password in a connection string unless you set Persist Security Info to true.

Además en la documentación referida al parámetro que sugiero infieren que el valor por defecto de `Persis Security Info` es `false`.

Adicionalmente sugiero utilizar [`Sql​Connection​String​Builder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7) para crear las cadenas de conexión dado las posibles ventajas.